# How could I create a function with Google Apps Script to add strikethrough to a row of cells if another cell's value met a condition?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, events, event-handling

The goal is to create a script that automatically adds strikethrough to text across a row when the last cell in a row's value is changed to "FOUND!"

This is what I have so far:

```
function strikethroughRow(row) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Records");
 
  const firstCell = "B" + row;
  const secondCell = "A" + row;
  
  firstCell.setFontLine("line-through"); 
  secondCell.setFontLine("line-through");
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const column = e.getColumn();
  const value = e.getValue();

  if(column === 3.0 && value === "FOUND!"){
    const row = e.getRow();
    strikethroughRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and your showing script, I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a value of "FOUND!" is put into column "C", you want to set the strikethrough to columns "A" and "B".

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `e.getColumn()`, `e.getValue()` and `e.getRow()` are not correct. In this case, it is required to use `e.range`.
- `firstCell` and `secondCell` are string value. By this, an error occurs.

I thought that in this case, the script might be able to be simpler. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const value = range.getValue();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 3 || value != "FOUND!") return;
  sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1).setFontLine("line-through");
}
```

#### Note:

- If the last column is not column "C", how about the following modified script?

  ```js
  function onEdit(e) {
    const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
    const { range } = e;
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    const value = range.getValue();
    const lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
    if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != lastColumn || value != "FOUND!") return;
    sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1).setFontLine("line-through");
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)